# Us of the ZSH shell "prompt" command

Tags: catalina, zsh

I'm new to MacOS command line/UNIX and trying to learn about it and the zsh shell. I have a book on Zsh shell and in an early section it describes use of the "prompt" command. However, my system does not seem to have this command. Any help as to how I can move forward would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share (screenshot if online, picture if paper) the section of the book describing the "prompt" command so it's easier to find out what it actually means?

Comment: Are you asking about the `PROMPT` environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

The macOS Catalina change the default Unix shell to zsh (pronounced zee...shell).
The .zshrc is the place that is similar to .bash_profile and .bashrc in the bash shell.

Before we start this, make sure your terminal is in zsh, otherwise change to zsh with `chsh -s /bin/zsh` command.

In your default directory

`# nano .zshrc`

Type the following:

`PROMPT="%d"`

Then run the profile

`# source .zshrc`

Here you go, got your prompt with only the current directory in your zsh prompt.

Here is my setup : `PROMPT="%d: %h-->"`
Which put a current directory and command history with `-->` in prompt.

Here is an in-depth description of how to customize your prompt:
https://scriptingosx.com/2019/07/moving-to-zsh-06-customizing-the-zsh-prompt/

To learn the difference of bash shell and zsh:
https://sunlightmedia.org/bash-vs-zsh/

A cool zsh prompt generation tool:
https://zsh-prompt-generator.site/